# How to execute a program with sudo rights but without the root context?

Tags: permissions, sudo, root

I want to start my IntelliJ IDEA with privileged rights. That is because when starting my Application within the IDE it starts a SFTP server. This is only working if I have the permission to do so.

Approach so far was to start the IntelliJ program with `sudo`. The inconvenience here was that IntelliJ started a whole new configuration context that now lies in the `root` directory. Therefore I have to start with a blank/new user configuration of the IDE (can be changed easily but that is not the point) and also I have to enter my licence code again.

Is there a way to simply execute a program without actually acting as root but still acting as the logged in user I am?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't run your SFTP server on a higher (unprivileged) port?

Comment: Try to run sftp in docker. Docker can be run as normal user after additional configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't run an IDE as root. That's asking for a lot of trouble if something goes wrong.

Instead, give yourself the right sudo access and wrap the item needing root access in a script.

For example, to run acme_sftp_server as root, create a script

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo acme_sftp_server
```

Then give yourself sudo privilege to run acme_sftp_server through sudo without a password.

Then invoke your script, not the server through IntelliJ